# CSS grid - last row item too big

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm building a little grid that will span the width of a page (i.e. no outside margins or padding) and include a gutter in-between each grid item.

My issue is that when the padding / gutter is removed from the last item, it causes this item to become larger than the other items.

[image]

See a Pen here:

http://codepen.io/backtofront/pen/yerpvX

The relevant item code is here:

```
[class*='column-'] {
 float: left;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 1px; 

 &:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
 }      

 img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to achieve this without adding padding / margin around each item.

Thank you.

Comment: The height (and width) of the image is being computed via the amount of space the image has. By removing the right padding on the last element(s), the last image has slightly more space to get larger, compared to the other images. If I remove your `last-of-type` selector, it fixed the problem, but leaves some padding on the right side, which I assume you don't want?

Comment: This is why flexbox was invented.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I see why it's behaving like it is. Yes that's the issue I'm facing - trying to get a full width row without the padding at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where I quite like how the bootstrap grid handles columns!

Here is a fiddle of your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/c24w1abL/

I replaced the `padding-right: 10px` on your column class with `padding-right: 5px;` and `padding-left: 5px`. This keeps all columns consistent. 
The .row gets a negative margin so that the column shifts back into line with the original column width.

The snippet below uses scss so I don't think the snippet will work? 
Please refer to the JSFiddle!

```css
/* Base
  -------------------------------------------------------- */

 html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 *, *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: inherit;
 }

  %clearfix {
    &:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
  }

/* Grids
  -------------------------------------------------------- */

  $grid-columns: 12; 

  .grid, .row {
    @extend %clearfix;
  }
  
  .row {
    margin: 0 -5px;
  }

  .grid {
    background: tomato;
  }

 [class*='column-'] {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px; 

    img {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
 }
     
  @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {

    .column-#{$i} { 
      width: 100% / $grid-columns * $i;
    }
  }
```

```html
/* Base
  -------------------------------------------------------- */

 html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 *, *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: inherit;
 }

  %clearfix {
    &:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
  }

/* Grids
  -------------------------------------------------------- */

  $grid-columns: 12; 

  .grid, .row {
    @extend %clearfix;
  }
  
  .row {
    margin: 0 -5px;
  }

  .grid {
    background: tomato;
  }

 [class*='column-'] {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px; 

    img {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
 }
     
  @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {

    .column-#{$i} { 
      width: 100% / $grid-columns * $i;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Very nice and simple solution to my problem, thank you.